# PHP - strtotime() and datetime strange behavior

Tags: php, mysql, string, datetime, strtotime

I have a some dates formatted as string in this format: `18-04-17`.
I want to convert them to dates.

At first I used strtotime() to change it to date:

```
$timestamp = strtotime($row['reqEndDate']);
$newdate = date("d-m-Y", $timestamp);
echo $newdate;
```

This outputs: `17-04-2018`. As you can see it mistakes the day with the year.

Next I tried to use datetime, as follows:

```
$newdate = datetime::createFromFormat("d-m-Y", $row['reqEndDate']);
echo $newdate->format('d-m-Y');
```

This outputs: `18-04-0017` .This method gets the day correctly, but instead of 2017 it prints 0017.

Is there any reason for this behavior? Maybe some settings in my php setup to look for?

Comment: remove strangness with `$newdate = datetime::createFromFormat("d-m-y", $row['reqEndDate']);`  a small `y` for `17` and a `Y` for `2017`, and `mistakes the day with the year` depends what timezone you have set.

Comment: Using `Y` for a 2-digit year is telling PHP that it's first century AD; using `y` is telling it that it's the current century

Comment: *"As you can see it mistakes the day with the year"* – I for one would *not* have known which is supposed to be which either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uppercase `Y` will produce 4 digit year. Lowercase `y` produces a two-digit year. Your code with DateTime should be:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y', $row['reqEndDate']);
echo $date->format('d-m-Y');
```

[You can read about supported formats in PHP's manual page about date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).